# How to iterate unequal nested lists to create a new list Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested-lists

I'm stuck on iterating several nested lists in order to calculate Call options by using a Python module, Mibian.

If I use mibian to calculate made up European call options.

```
import mibian as mb

mb.BS([stock price, strike price, interest rate, days to maturity], volatility)


my_list = [[20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45], 
           [50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 77, 98, 101],
           [30, 40, 50, 60]]
```

For calculating multiple call options, first, I create a range.
If I select, say the first nested list, `my_list[0]`, and run a `for`-loop. I get all the call options for the stock.

```
range_list = list(range(len(my_list)))
range_list
# [0, 1, 2]

data = dict()
for x in range_list:
    data[x] = option2 = []

    for i in my_list[0]:

        c = mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20 ], 10)

        option2.append(c.callPrice)

option2
```

This gives the 6 call prices of the first nested list from my_list.

Output:

```
 [100.01095590221843,
  95.013694877773034,
  90.016433853327641,
  85.019172828882233,
  80.021911804436854,
  75.024650779991447]
```

What I'm trying to figure out, is how I can iterate all the nested lists in one go, and get a new list of nested lists that contain  the call option prices for `my_list[0]`, `my_list[1]`, and `my_list[2]`.

I'd like this output in one go for all three nested lists.

Output:

```
 [[100.01095590221843,    [70.027389755546068,    [90.016433853327641,
  95.013694877773034,     68.028485345767905,     80.021911804436854, 
  90.016433853327641,     66.029580935989742,     80.021911804436854,
  85.019172828882233,     64.030676526211579,     70.027389755546068,
  80.021911804436854,     62.03177211643343,      ]]
  75.024650779991447]     60.032867706655267,
                          43.042180223540925,
                          22.05368392087027,
                          19.055327306203068]
```

Can anyone help? I'm sure it's something very simple that I'm missing.
Many thanks.
P.S. I can't get the indentation right when editing my code on here.

Comment: please edit your question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the link, Bhansa. I've edited it, but if I edit out too much, it'll lose a lot of information pertaining to the question. Shame I still keep getting down voted on this question.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. IIUC, get rid of `range_list = list(range(len(my_list)))`, `for x in range_list:`, `data[x] = option2 = []` and `for i in my_list[0]:`. Substitute this for `for i in my_list: for j in i: c = mb.BS([120, j, 1, 20 ], 10)` with nested indentation. Is that getting towards your goal? Am I along the right lines for what you're trying to do?

Comment: How come that `my_list[2]` contains 4 elements but the expected return has 5?

Comment: Hi MSeifert, oh thanks for pointing that out. It's just a mistake on my part with the editing. You're referring to the last row in my_list[2], 60.03286....., it's actually just a duplicate from my_list[1] when I was copying and pasting. I'll edit it out, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your current approach:

```
range_list = list(range(len(my_list)))

data = dict()
for x in range_list:
    data[x] = option2 = []
    for i in my_list[0]:
        c = mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20 ], 10)
        option2.append(c.callPrice)
```

The first thing you should note is that there is `enumerate` to get the index and the part at the same time, so you can omit the `range_list` variable:

```
data = dict()
for x, sublist in enumerate(my_list):
    data[x] = option2 = []
    for i in my_list[0]:
        c = mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20 ], 10)
        option2.append(c.callPrice)
```

This also takes care of the problem with the "dynamic indexing" because you can just iterate over the `sublist`:

```
data = dict()
for x, sublist in enumerate(my_list):
    data[x] = option2 = []
    for i in sublist:
        c = mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20 ], 10)
        option2.append(c.callPrice)
```

Then you can use a list comprehension to replace the inner loop:

```
data = dict()
for x, sublist in enumerate(my_list):
    data[x] = [mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20 ], 10).callPrice for i in sublist]
```

and if you feel like you want this shorter (not recommended but some like it) then use a dict comprehension instead of the outer loop:

```
data = {x: [mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20 ], 10).callPrice for i in sublist] 
        for x, sublist in enumerate(my_list)}
```

Comment: Good re-work! Beat me to it. But am I missing something, what about `callPrice` method?

Comment: @Parfait You're right, I missed that. I edited the code, it should be correct now.

Comment: Oh, wow! Thank you MSeifert! And thanks to everyone else who helped! :) I've been struggling on this for a couple of days, tiring. Hence I posted an initially messy question. So you created a list within a dictionary, very cool! Hope that helps anyone else with iterating nested loops and/or calculating options.

Comment: @MichaelRSF I'm curious as to why you've accepted the other answer that doesn't appear to solve your problem at all. Your _initial_ code also attempts to create a dictionary.

Comment: Hi rogan, I'm still a newbie to Python. I've only taken it up about 1-2 months ago. When I created dictionaries, I wasn't able to grab nested loops for the calculated call prices. Othertimes, the data dictionaries were messy.  Yeah, I unaccepted the incorrect answer. Also, I'm not that advance with dictionaries.

Comment: @MichaelRSF You should get the "list of list" result if you use `[[mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20 ], 10).callPrice for i in sublist] for sublist in my_list]`.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! I was wondering, if  `dates_list= [5, 10, 20]` for each respective nested list in `my_list`, how would i be able to iterate both `my_list` and `dates_list` together? So, instead of `mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20], 10)` it was something like `mb.BS([120, i, 1, x], 10)` where x is the `dates_list`. I did another for-loop under `for i in sublist:`, `for x in dates_list:` then `c= mb.BS([120, i, 1, x], 10)`, but for say, data[2], instead of expecting 4 call prices, i get 12. The 'dates_list' multiplies each nested list by 3. Can anyone please help on this last part?

Comment: @MichaelRSF You can use `zip` if you want them "combined" or `itertools.product` if you want the cartesian product. If you need more detailed help please ask another question. It's hard to do follow-up questions in comments. :)

Comment: Yep, you're right. Posting a question in a comment is too difficult. I posted a new question. I tried the list(zip(days_left, my_list)) with some code, but it gave me an error :/  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334794/how-to-iterate-nested-lists-with-another-list-to-create-a-dictionary-of-lists-py`

Answer (score 0):

provided that

```
my_nested_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9]]
[i for i in my_nested_list]
```

returns

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

something along

```
my_list = [[20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45], [50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 77, 98, 101],
      [30, 40, 50, 60]]    
[mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20 ], 10) for i in my_list]
```

shall return what you expect?

Comment: From what I understand, you need nested iteration. One to access the sublist, then to access individual values within the sublist.

Comment: Also, there's a `callPrice` method.