# How to iterate nested lists with another list to create a dictionary of lists Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, nested-lists

I'm using Mibian module to calculate call options. I have a list of three nested lists. Each nested list represent strike prices. Each nested list has their own respective days left to expiration, i.e. my_list[2] has 30 days left.

```
     import mibian as mb
     import pandas as pd

     my_list = [[20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45], 
       [50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 77, 98, 101],
       [30, 40, 50, 60]]

     days_left = [5, 12, 30]

     my_list[2]
     [30, 40, 50, 60]

     days_left[2]
     30
```

The structure of a Mibian Black-Scholes code for calculating the call option.

```
    mb.BS([stock price, strike price, interest rate, days to maturity], volatility)

     data1 = dict()
     for x, sublist in enumerate(my_list):
         data1[x] = option3 = []
         for i in sublist:
             c = mb.BS([120, i, 1, 20], 10)
             option3.append(c.callPrice)
```

The gives an output of a dictionary with 3 lists, the call prices based on each of the three nested lists from my_list.

```
        data1

         {0: [100.01095590221843,
              95.013694877773034,
              90.016433853327641,
              85.019172828882233,
              80.021911804436854,
              75.024650779991447],
         1: [70.027389755546068,
             68.028485345767905,
             66.029580935989742,
             64.030676526211579,
             62.03177211643343,
             60.032867706655267,
             43.042180223540925,
             22.05368392087027,
             19.055327306203068],
         2: [90.016433853327641,
             80.021911804436854,
             70.027389755546068,
             60.032867706655267]}
```

What I'm trying to get is for both the nested lists and the dates to be iterated together

I'd like to create the same as above, with a dictionary, but that iterates not only my_list, but also the days_left in order.

I tried a zip list by new_list = list(zip(days_left, my_list)), but it gave me an error. Can anyone please help? Many thanks.

```
    new_list = list(zip(my_list, days_left))

    [([20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45], 5),
     ([50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 77, 98, 101], 12),
     ([30, 40, 50, 60], 30)]

    data5 = dict()
    for x, days_left, my_list in enumerate(new_list):
             data5[x] = option5 = []
             for days_left, my_list in new_list:
                           c = mb.BS([120, my_list, 1, days_left ], 10)
                           option5.append(c.callPrice)
```

For a single nested list like my_list[2]. The output is:

```
    range_list = list(range(1))

data2 = dict()
for x in range_list:
data2[x] = option2 = []

for i in my_list[2]:

    c = mb.BS([120, i, 1, 30  ], 10)

    option2.append(c.callPrice)

option2


[90.024647403788975,
 80.032863205051967,
 70.041079006314973,
 60.049294807577965]
```

The values are similar, but not the same as those in data1[2]. The ideal output should have the same structure as data1, with three dictionaries, but the values slightly different due to the days_left. The differences may seem trivial, but later, I'll have to multiply them by 100, so those differences build up.

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: Hi Austin, it should look like the dictionary in data1 above, and the values should look similar, but with the days_left taken into account. So for example,                    `range_list = list(range(1))

data2 = dict()
for x in range_list:
    data2[x] = option2 = []

    for i in my_list[2]:

        c = mb.BS([120, i, 1, 30  ], 10)

        option2.append(c.callPrice)

option2`   The output values will look similar to data1[2], `[90.024647403788975,
 80.032863205051967,
 70.041079006314973,
 60.049294807577965] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. Please note, most of this is trying to simulate your environment - you only care about the last couple of lines.

That said, a data structure indexed by sequential numbers shouldn't be a dict, it should be a list. ;-)

```
Magic_numbers = [
    100.01095590221843,
    95.013694877773034,
    90.016433853327641,
    85.019172828882233,
    80.021911804436854,
    75.024650779991447,
    70.027389755546068,
    68.028485345767905,
    66.029580935989742,
    64.030676526211579,
    62.03177211643343,
    60.032867706655267,
    43.042180223540925,
    22.05368392087027,
    19.055327306203068,
    90.016433853327641,
    80.021911804436854,
    70.027389755546068,
    60.032867706655267,
]

Magic_index = 0

def mb(details, volatility):
    class C:
        def __init__(self, n):
            self.callPrice = n

    global Magic_index
    result = C(Magic_numbers[Magic_index])
    Magic_index += 1
    return result

mb.BS = mb

strike_prices = [
    [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
    [50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 77, 98, 101],
    [30, 40, 50, 60]
]

days_left = [5, 12, 30]

data99 = {}  # This is silly. A dict indexed by sequential numbers should be a list.

for i, (days, prices) in enumerate(zip(days_left, strike_prices)):
    data99[i] = [mb.BS([120, price, 1, days], 10).callPrice for price in prices]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(data99)
```

The output looks like this:

```
{0: [100.01095590221843,
     95.01369487777303,
     90.01643385332764,
     85.01917282888223,
     80.02191180443685,
     75.02465077999145],
 1: [70.02738975554607,
     68.0284853457679,
     66.02958093598974,
     64.03067652621158,
     62.03177211643343,
     60.03286770665527,
     43.042180223540925,
     22.05368392087027,
     19.05532730620307],
 2: [90.01643385332764,
     80.02191180443685,
     70.02738975554607,
     60.03286770665527]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the cool code, Austin. Unfortunately, it's giving the same values as the one I originally did. So kind of confused as to why that's the case :S The last 4 rows should have the exact same values as the `option2` of  `[90.024647403788975,
 80.032863205051967,
 70.041079006314973,
 60.049294807577965]`

Comment: The code I wrote just uses numbers that I copied and pasted from you. Are you using it with your "real" mb.BS function, or the fake one I provided?

Comment: Hey Austin, I re-checked your code, and didn't use the function you created. I just used the line of code that begins with data99, and it worked! Really greatful! :) Thanks for the help Austin!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be as simple as:

```
for x, (days_left, my_list) in enumerate(new_list):
     data5[x] = option5 = []
     for days_left, my_list in new_list:
          c = mb.BS([120, my_list, 1, days_left ], 10)
                    option5.append(c.callPrice)
```

Because the output of `enumerate` will be in the form `(i, x)`, where in this case `x` is a tuple (i.e. `(i, (x, y))`).

Comment: Hey ocasbranson, thanks for the input, makes sense, but it doesn't seem to work. Keep getting `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not a 'list'` Been working on this for almost 3 days, so may just throw in the towel, and move on. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in one of the inputs to `cm.BS`? But impossible to tell from that info. Try picking apart your loop and getting it to print parameters before it runs things, then you can find out where it's failing, and what parameters it's passing to the function.